# Accessing the ZOmbie thread stack in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a parallel question.

let's assume the following method which is running by a thread(A).

```
void run(){
//some work
  FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("/home/share/_config"));
//some work with fis
}
```

and assume there is a error which is not catchable, so as I got from java threading, we can add a uncaught exception manager with `setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` method, so the question is, how would I access the file I opened (`fis`) from the killed thread stack and close it from the handler?

Comment: If you use a `finally` clause to close your `FileInputStream`, there is no problem here.  There is also a new syntax in Java 7 that lets you specify things that need to be closed, in parentheses, in your `try` clause

Comment: Note that `FileInputStream` is declared as throwing a checked exception.

Comment: Either your code is well written and cleans resources nicely or its a mess and you can't fix it.  Pretending a mess can be tidied up around the edges is making a bad situation worse IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: Code works in Java 7+

Don't do this! Usually, the method that opens a stream should also close it! Put the stream in a try-with-resource clause, then it will be closed automatically:

```
void run() {
    //some work
    try (FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("/home/share/_config"))) {
        //some work with fis
    }
}
```

The stream `fis` will be closed, if the execution flow leaves the `try` block - either because it finishes its work or due to an exception.

It is also possible to open multiple input streams in the same try-with-resource clause by using a semicolon (;) as separator. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for details.

Comment: so what about multiple resources, it is going to have nested `try(){}` blocks, does it work too?! and generally except this example, how would I access the stack really?

Comment: No, you can have multiple resources within the try clause separated by semicolon (;)

Comment: If you open the stream inside the run method and do not publish it somewhere, it is not possible to access it from outside! (The scope of the InputStream variable is the method, so no chance!)

Comment: so what if there is a condition to create a resource, I cannot just initialize them up by default, there is to much conditions, also is it possible to declare the variable with `try` and initialize it later?

Comment: No. Initialization must happen within the try clause. Check the conditions before you open it. If you have multiple resources to open, you can of course also nest the try statements.

Comment: Thanks dude, so as I'm seeing there is no any chance to access a zombie stack in java. you helped to much :D